# Rock Paper Scissors using JS but not how many times a player won doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

New to JS and having a problem. The problem is that ***how many times a player won is not working well***. If it's boring to watch the code then just show me a way to edit it. I wrote exactly the same code in python and it was working well, IDK what's wrong with JS or whatever...

I know there are other problems with UI design, ignore it :D.

```js
const rpsGame = (user) => {
  userChoise = user.id;

  var bot = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

  if (bot == 0) {
    var botChoise = "rock";
  } else if (bot == 1) {
    botChoise = "paper";
  } else {
    botChoise = "scissors";
  }

  let userWins = 0;
  let botWins = 0;

  if (userChoise == botChoise) {
    document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Tied!";
  } else if (userChoise == "rock" && botChoise == "scissors") {
    let won = (document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Won!");
    userWins += 1;
    document.querySelector(".userWins").textContent = userWins;
  } else if (userChoise == "rock" && botChoise == "paper") {
    document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Lost!";
    botWins += 1;
    document.querySelector(".userWins").textContent = botWins;
  } else if (userChoise == "paper" && botChoise == "rock") {
    document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Won!";
    userWins += 1;
    document.querySelector(".userWins").textContent = userWins;
  } else if (userChoise == "paper" && botChoise == "scissors") {
    document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Lost!";
    botWins += 1;
    document.querySelector(".userWins").textContent = botWins;
  } else if (userChoise == "scissors" && botChoise == "paper") {
    document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Won!";
    userWins += 1;
    document.querySelector(".userWins").textContent = userWins;
  } else if (userChoise == "scissors" && botChoise == "rock") {
    document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Lost!";
    botWins += 1;
    document.querySelector(".userWins").textContent = botWins;
  }

  if (botChoise == "rock") {
    let rock = document.querySelector("#scissors");
    rock.setAttribute("src", "/rockPaperScissors/img/rock.jpg");
  } else if (botChoise == "paper") {
    let paper = document.querySelector("#scissors");
    paper.setAttribute("src", "/rockPaperScissors/img/paper.jpg");
  } else {
    let scissors = document.querySelector("#scissors");
    scissors.setAttribute("src", "/rockPaperScissors/img/scissors.jpg");
  }

  if (userChoise == "rock") {
    let rock = document.querySelector("#rock");
    rock.setAttribute("src", "/rockPaperScissors/img/rock.jpg");
  } else if (userChoise == "paper") {
    let paper = document.querySelector("#rock");
    paper.setAttribute("src", "/rockPaperScissors/img/paper.jpg");
  } else {
    let scissors = document.querySelector("#rock");
    scissors.setAttribute("src", "/rockPaperScissors/img/scissors.jpg");
  }
};
```

```css
.main {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.main h1 {
  animation: color-change 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0% {
    color: blue;
  }
  10% {
    color: #8e44ad;
  }
  20% {
    color: #1abc9c;
  }
  30% {
    color: #d35400;
  }
  40% {
    color: blue;
  }
  50% {
    color: #34495e;
  }
  60% {
    color: blue;
  }
  70% {
    color: #2980b9;
  }
  80% {
    color: #f1c40f;
  }
  90% {
    color: #2980b9;
  }
  100% {
    color: pink;
  }
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.container #rock,
.container #paper,
.container #scissors {
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.container #rock:hover,
.container #paper:hover,
.container #scissors:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgba(220, 20, 60, 0.7) 0px 0px 40px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.header .choose {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: auto 0 0px 0;
  color: cadetblue;
}

.header .result {
  margin: auto 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1 style="font-family: sans-serif; text-align: center; margin-top: 50px">
    Rock Paper Scissors
  </h1>
  <div class="header">
    <h2 class="userWins result">0</h2>
    <h2 class="choose">Choose One</h2>
    <h2 class="botWins result">0</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img/rock.jpg" alt="rock" width="150" height="150" id="rock" onclick="rpsGame(this)" draggable="false" />
    <img src="img/paper.jpg" alt="paper" width="150" height="150" id="paper" onclick="rpsGame(this)" draggable="false" />
    <img src="img/scissors.jpg" alt="scissors" width="150" height="150" id="scissors" onclick="rpsGame(this)" draggable="false" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a sidenote: You should not use so many `if/else statements`. They can have a negative impact on performance. a `switch statement` would be the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:**

Variables `botWins` and `userWins`, which hold winning counts, need to be moved out of the `rpsGame` function. At the moment they are set to zero on each call to the function.

The wrong element is being updated for `botWins`. Replace `userWins` with `botWins` in lines currently coded as:

```
 document.querySelector('.userWins').textContent = botWins
```

(Multiple lines affected and probably a cut and paste error. Raised in comment by @MarkM)

---

**Suggestion**:
If you write JavaScript in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) the compiler will tell you about errors that go unnoticed  - like not declaring `userChoise` in the code.

(If you write JavaScript in sloppy mode, assignment to an undeclared variable automatically creates the variable *in global scope*!)

---

**About Code Snippets:**  you can format your code as a code snippet so readers can run it to see what it does. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) help and search for "code snippets".

---

**Code snippet example** using corrected code  and a `console.log` of wins and choices made:

```js
"use strict";
  let userWins = 0;
  let botWins = 0;
  const rpsGame = (user) => {
    const userChoise = user.id;

    var bot = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    if (bot == 0) {
        var botChoise = "rock";
    } else if (bot == 1) {
        botChoise = "paper";
    } else {
        botChoise = "scissors";
    }

    if (userChoise == botChoise) {
        document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Tied!";
    } else if (userChoise == "rock" && botChoise == "scissors") {
        let won = document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Won!";
        userWins += 1
        document.querySelector('.userWins').textContent = userWins
    } else if (userChoise == "rock" && botChoise == "paper") {
        document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Lost!";
        botWins += 1
        document.querySelector('.botWins').textContent = botWins
    } else if (userChoise == "paper" && botChoise == "rock") {
        document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Won!";
        userWins += 1
        document.querySelector('.userWins').textContent = userWins
    } else if (userChoise == "paper" && botChoise == "scissors") {
        document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Lost!";
        botWins += 1
        document.querySelector('.botWins').textContent = botWins
    } else if (userChoise == "scissors" && botChoise == "paper") {
        document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Won!";
        userWins += 1
        document.querySelector('.userWins').textContent = userWins
    } else if (userChoise == "scissors" && botChoise == "rock") {
        document.querySelector(".choose").textContent = "You Lost!";
        botWins += 1
        document.querySelector('.botWins').textContent = botWins
    }

console.clear();
console.log("botChoise: %s, userChoise: %s, botWins: %s, userWins: %s", botChoise, userChoise, botWins, userWins);

    if (botChoise == "rock") {
        let rock = document.querySelector("#scissors");
        rock.setAttribute("src", "/rockPaperScissors/img/rock.jpg");
    } else if (botChoise == "paper") {
        let paper = document.querySelector("#scissors");
        paper.setAttribute("src", "/rockPaperScissors/img/paper.jpg");
    } else {
        let scissors = document.querySelector("#scissors");
        scissors.setAttribute("src", "/rockPaperScissors/img/scissors.jpg");
    }

    if (userChoise == "rock") {
        let rock = document.querySelector("#rock");
        rock.setAttribute("src", "/rockPaperScissors/img/rock.jpg");
    } else if (userChoise == "paper") {
        let paper = document.querySelector("#rock");
        paper.setAttribute("src", "/rockPaperScissors/img/paper.jpg");
    } else {
        let scissors = document.querySelector("#rock");
        scissors.setAttribute("src", "/rockPaperScissors/img/scissors.jpg");
    }

};
```

```css
.main {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto auto;
}

.main h1 {
    animation: color-change 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes color-change {
    0% {
        color: blue;
    }
    10% {
        color: #8e44ad;
    }
    20% {
        color: #1abc9c;
    }
    30% {
        color: #d35400;
    }
    40% {
        color: blue;
    }
    50% {
        color: #34495e;
    }
    60% {
        color: blue;
    }
    70% {
        color: #2980b9;
    }
    80% {
        color: #f1c40f;
    }
    90% {
        color: #2980b9;
    }
    100% {
        color: pink;
    }
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 75px;
}

.container #rock,
.container #paper,
.container #scissors {
    transition: 0.1s;
}

.container #rock:hover,
.container #paper:hover,
.container #scissors:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: rgba(220, 20, 60, 0.7) 0px 0px 40px;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.header .choose {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: auto 0 0px 0;
    color: cadetblue;
}

.header .result {
    margin: auto 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <h1 style="font-family: sans-serif; text-align: center; margin-top: 50px;">Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
    <div class="header">
        <h2 class="userWins result">0</h2>
        <h2 class="choose">Choose One</h2>
        <h2 class="botWins result">0</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="img/rock.jpg" alt="rock" width="150" height="150" id="rock" onclick="rpsGame(this)"
            draggable="false">
        <img src="img/paper.jpg" alt="paper" width="150" height="150" id="paper" onclick="rpsGame(this)"
            draggable="false">
        <img src="img/scissors.jpg" alt="scissors" width="150" height="150" id="scissors" onclick="rpsGame(this)"
            draggable="false">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks now I see it's working I should focus on it